# Calling method with enum parameters from buttons

Tags: unity

I have the following enum:

```
public enum WeaponType { Sword, Spear, Blunt, Ranged }
```

And I have the following public methods on a component:

```
public void MyMethod1(int myparam) { ... }
public void MyMethod2(WeaponType myparam) { ... }
```

Why is it that when I try to call my methods from a `Button` component, I can not see the ones that use enumerations as parameters?

[image]

Comment: You can't, Unity's inspector isn't set up to handle it. Good news, integers are directly convertable to enum values.

Comment: @Draco18s How? Also please consider post this as an answer. :)

Comment: @Draco18s Albeit easy to Google (as a matter of fact I already did and found it), it's better to give off the info directly. Same-ish policy as "no link-only answers". In case you ain't coming back, y'all only need casting: `(EMyEnum)myInt` (works both way round too!)

Comment: @JeromeJ Comments don't count as answers and aren't subject to the same rules.

Answer (score 2):

As Draco18s stated in comments, sadly, you can't.

Thankfully, if it helps, you can still just cast it back and forth:

```
EMyEnum myEmum = (EMyEnum)myInt;

// Or.
int myInt = (int)myEnum;
```